# Named JSON-RPC params using jsonrpc Rust crate

Tags: rust, json-rpc

I need to build JSON-RPC server that supports request params by name rather than by position. This should allow mapping params into structures for sake of maintainability and extensibility.

As far as I can see `jsonrpc-derive` crate doesn't support code generation for this scenario if not to pass such a structure as a first parameter (which will uglify my API specification). So I have to define handlers via `add_method()`, serialize `Params::Map` back into JSON and deserialize again into my param structure. This looks pretty ridiculous and inefficient. Do I have another alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like after [client-side named parameters were added](https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpc/pull/541) a proposal was made for [client-side named parameters](https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpc/pull/634), however it stalled and was never merged.

However the entire crate seems to have stalled / died. If you're building a json-rpc *server*, maybe you just... don't need to bother with it anywa? jsonrpc is not exactly a complex format.